# Можно добавить UMD только одной определённой входной точке?

Tags: webpack

Есть несколько точек входа:

```js
entry: {
        a: "./a",
        b: "./b"
}
```

Как добавить UMD только для одной конкретной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением является [multiple configurations](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#multiple-configurations)

Пример:

```js
module.exports = [
    {
        entry: { a: "./a"},
        output: {
            path: __dirname,
            filename: "a.js"
        }
    },
    {
        entry: { b: "./b"},
        output: {
            path: __dirname,
            filename: "b.js",
            library: "MyLibrary",
            libraryTarget: "umd"
        }
    }
];
```